# Using DataParallel with two GPUs is much slower than using one GPU

Tags: pytorch, multi-gpu, dataparallel

Recently I've been learning Pytorch to train models using multiple GPUs, and one of the first things I started to experiment with was DataParallel (even though it's a method that's discouraged to use), and I constructed some dummy data, as well as a toy model, with the code:

```
from datasets import load_dataset
from torch.utils.data import Dataset, DataLoader
import torch
import time

class My_dataset(Dataset):
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = torch.randn((15000, 768))
        self.y = torch.ones((15000,))
    
    def __getitem__(self, idx):
        return self.x[idx], self.y[idx]
    
    def __len__(self):
        return len(self.x)

class My_Model(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.linear1 = torch.nn.Linear(768, 76800)
        self.relu = torch.nn.ReLU()
        self.classfier = torch.nn.Linear(76800, 1)
        self.loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()
    
    def forward(self, x):
        result = self.classfier(self.relu(self.linear1(x)))
        return result


train_dataset = My_dataset()
train_dataloader = DataLoader(train_dataset, batch_size=8, shuffle=True, drop_last=False)    


model = My_Model()
model = model.cuda()
# model = torch.nn.parallel.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[0,1])

loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss()

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(params=model.parameters())
start = time.time()
for i, batch_datasets in enumerate(train_dataloader):
    if i % 100 == 0:
        print(f"i: {i}")
    x, y = batch_datasets
    x = x.cuda()
    y = y.cuda()
    
    result = model(x)
    loss = loss_fn(result, y)
    optimizer.zero_grad()
    loss.backward()
    optimizer.step()
end = time.time()
print(f"time is {end - start}")
```

I run the code and it prints: **time is 2.7407000064849854**

Next, I uncommented `model = torch.nn.parallel.DataParallel(model, device_ids=[0,1])`, i.e., I trained the model using two GPUs, and the printout is: **time is 50.398988246917725**

**I find it very confusing that training a model using two GPUs is much slower than one GPU.**

Additionally, I printed the memory taken up by running a single GPU: 1513MiB / 24268MiB, and two GPUs (batch size is the same as a single GPU): [1785MiB / 24268MiB, 1331MiB / 24268MiB].  **I don't know if this is normal for memory.**

Comment: You should consider raising this concern at the [PyTorch forum](https://discuss.pytorch.org/). There are PyTorch experts who might better answer your question.

Comment: Afaik, to use `nn.parallel.DataParallel`, you would also need to wrap your model's layers with `nn.DataParallel`. In your case, `self.linear1 = nn.DataParallel(self.linear1)`. You can check [this](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/former_torchies/parallelism_tutorial.html?highlight=dataparallel#:~:text=Data%20Parallelism%20is%20implemented%20using,GPUs%20in%20the%20batch%20dimension.) for reference.